# Insert image in shiny dashboard: shiny flex dashboard failed

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I run shiny in flex dashboard template in markdown. 
I want to insert images in tab but it always shows me

```
Warning in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="figure-html/unnamed-chunk-8-1.mb.png": The system cannot find the path specified
```

And the dashboard output shows nothing. Has anyone encounters the issue before?

If just want to insert the image no other coding for graphs etc, then it works

````
  ---
 title: "Untitled"
 output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: columns
  vertical_layout: fill
   runtime: shiny
  ---

   ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
   library(flexdashboard)
   library(shiny)
   ```

   Column {data-width=350}
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
   ![alt](/Users/abc/Desktop/cluster.png)
````

if add other codes for other graphs ,  ex ,  the dashboard shows nothing .but if remove the insert image part , the dashboard is perfect

````
     Column {data-width=500}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------


    ### Data     
    ```{r}

    DT::datatable(table_fm, options = list(pageLength = 10))

    ```

    Column {data-width=350}
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
   ![alt](/Users/abc/Desktop/cluster.png)
````

Comment: Are you sure you give the correct path? It looks strange. If you need further help, please provide the relevant code

Comment: should I use fig.path=  in the chunk ?

Comment: After I dont use plotly function just use ggplot alone, then image can be inserted without issues .